# Wordpress automatically appends a "2" to a URL. How can we remove this?

Tags: wordpress, url

on a wordpress site we had created a subpage example.tld/landingpage/. After removing this subpage and adding it again, wordpress now automatically appends a 2 to the URL: example.tld/landingpage-2/. We would like to restore and use the original version without the 2 in the URL. The old page cannot be found in the trash. A contribution page or a category page with the same name does not exist. About the URL change function in the backend it does not work. How do I get this -2 out of the URL again? Do you have any idea what this could be and how we can fix the problem? Last possibility is to delete the page from the database. But I don't want to do that if possible. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload an image with the name of landingpage? Could you please check the URL **example.tld/landingpage** ?

And also see if there is a drafted page with that name.